# Custom link is redirecting without subfolder in URL - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect, subdirectory

Wordpress is eating up a subfolder within my links.

My wordpress menu is set up by adding pages and custom links under the pages. Each page has several sections/paragraphs that I've link-anchored and I'm using custom links to refer to their URL.

For example: The page "Glass" has two custom links under it - "Double Pane" and "Single Pane". The "Glass" URL is found at example.com/glass and the two custom links at example.com/glass/#double-pane and example.com/glass/#single-pane respectively.

The links work just fine from the homepage. However, when I end up at one of the other pages and click on one of the custom links then the browser inputs the URL without the appropriate subfolder. So if I'm at example.com/glass and I click on example.com/glass/#double-pane then the browser inputs example.com/#double-pane which spits me back out to the homepage.

Any ideas on what could be causing this? I deactivated all plugins and the problem persists.

My .htaccess looks standard and I'm up to date on wordpress (4.5.3)

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin for url redirect https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Chandru. But I'm not trying to redirect. I'm trying to fix the problem with wordpress generating a different URL than the one that's clicked on. As a temporary fix I tried writing in URL redirects from the URL that wordpress spits out to the actual URL I'm trying to get to and it didn't work. It still loads the URL without the subfolder in it.